# Im trying to make a code to calculate perimeter however the result is 0.0 units

Tags: java

My support class

```
/*  
 *Calculates Perimeter of three triangles
 */

public class Triangle{
  //data field declarations
  public int x1;        // coordinates of first point of the triangle
  public int y1;
  public int x2;       // coordinates of second point of the triangle
  public int y2;
  public int x3;      // coordinates of third point of the triangle
  public int y3;
  private double side1, side2, side3, perimeter;
  private String m;

  public Triangle(String m, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3)
  {
    this.m = m;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.x3 = x3;
    this.y3 = y3;
  }

  public void calculateSideLength()
  {
    side1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)*Math.pow((y2-y1),2));
    side2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x2),2)*Math.pow((y3-y2),2));
    side3 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x1),2)*Math.pow((y3-y1),2));
  }

  public void calculateTrianglePerimeter()
  {
    perimeter = side1+side2+side3;
  }

   public String toString()
  {
    return "Triangle " + m +  " perimeter is " + perimeter + " units";
   }
 }
```

My application class

```
/*  
 *Calculates Perimeter of three triangles
 */

public class TriangleApp{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Triangle a = new Triangle("A", 0,3,3,4,1,9);
    System.out.println(a.toString());
  }
}
```

I get Triangle A perimeter is 0.0 units
Could someone tell me what im i doing wrong?

Comment: May be you lost methods calling in method main. Your class constructor does not call methods which calculate value of perimeter field

Answer (score 4):

You're not calling `calculateSideLength()`, or `calculateTrianglePerimeter()`. Call those (from the constructor, in that order, or from the user code) and the values will be set.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the function `calculateTrianglePerimeter()` after creating the Triangle Object, though the implementation is there. What you can do is, towards the end of the constructor, call the necessary functions, in proper order, to calculate the attributes such as side length and perimeter.